# How to achieve this shifted background color of a text-container in CSS (or JS)?

Tags: css, css-position, background-color

[image: text effect background color shifted]

Can someone help me on how to achieve this dynamic shifted color box of a text container in CSS? It should be dynamic to handle long headlines breaking into two lines.

If CSS can't handle this, I am open to JS solutions.

```
h1 span {
color: black;
background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```
<h1><span>HEADLINE<br>LONGER</span></h1>
```

With a span I can limit the background color to the actual length of the text, but I don't know how to shift it ?

tried this and was closest I can get, but can't wrap my head around the break of text also, as markup won't work in content property:

```css
h1 span:before {  
 content:"'HEADLINE'+'<br/>'+'LONGER'";
  color: #F4BEBE;
  background-color: #F4BEBE;
  top: 40px;
  left: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<h1><span>HEADLINE<br>LONGER</span></h1>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`box-decoration-break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-decoration-break) and [`linear-gradient()`/](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient)[`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position):

```css
h1 span {
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #f4bebe, #f4bebe);
  background-position: 10px 15px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-inline-end: 10px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}


/* Demo only */

* {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: system-ui;
}
```

```html
<h1><span>Headline</span></h1>

<h1><span>Hello world</span></h1>

<h1><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think you're almost there. Here's an hack I tried out. I know there must be some other solution out there but this is quick and hacky if you don't mind. I added comments in the code. Take care

```css
.one {
margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.paragraph {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 40px; /*adjust as you wish*/
  margin: 0 0 10px; /* adjust as you want */
}

.paragraph:before {  
  content:"";
  color: #F4BEBE;
  background-color: #F4BEBE;
  top: 15px; /* adjust as you wish */
  left: 10px; /* adjust as you wish */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; /* adjust as you wanted */
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <span class="paragraph">Headline</span>
  <br/>
  <span class="paragraph">Hero Master league</span>
  <br/>
  <span class="paragraph">Good Morning</span>
</div>
  

<div>
  <span class="paragraph">Headline on two,</span>
  <br/>  
  <span class="paragraph">lines here</span>
</div>
```

Comment: That's already pretty good - thanks!

The only problem is, that this doesn't work with text breaking automatically. Then the whole row is red instead of only the area of text. is there a solution for that bit?

Comment: Opened here on mobile ad then it looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/7iKl86l